# I need help finding wildcard to use in mysql funcion JSON_SEARCH

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I'm tring to get the right wildcard (trying [0-9]%) using:

```
JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'one', 'openstack-neutron-[0-9]%', null, '$.packages[*]')
```

I just need to get "openstack-neutron-12.1.0-2-el7ost.noarch"
but not all the
"openstack-neutron-blabla1-14.5.5-el7ost.noarch"
"openstack-neutron-blabla2-12.1.0-2-el7ost.noarch"
...

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: the search patter works like String LIKE and not like regular expassion

Comment: yes, you are right. But I think [] it's also a like operator or I'm wrong? I saw this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: it is as i sad wildcars are for strings and how to search them, as it is expalined in the link you provided a search pattern that shows that you want regular expressions )the numbers part), this is possible, but you provioded not enough data examples, so that we can build one for you

Answer (score 1):

So your seachstring must start with  `openstack-neutron-` and end with `-12.1.0-2-el7ost.noarch`

USE

```
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'one', 'openstack-neutron-%', null, '$.packages[*]') IS NOT NULL 
    AND JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'one', '%-12.1.0-2-el7ost.noarch', null, '$.packages[*]') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. That way JSON_SEARCH will catch just the "12.1.0-2". I need one that catches just openstack-neutron-<all version>. I just need to force that the first character after "neutron-" is a number, but can't find a way.

Comment: please give an example of your json JSON is a string so you can use reguzlar expressions with it, it is onyl more complicated

Comment: I did try with regex and that worked partially. I'm trying to make a JSON_SEARCH with the 'one' parameter. What that does is he finds the first match and go to next record. Because of that I have to include a regex on the JSON_SEARCH and not after JSON_SEARCH. I don't know how to include regex on JSON_SEARCH.

Comment: as long as you are search especially for numbers there you have lost. so show us the pattern that you used and show us also the json data

Comment: openstack-neutron-1-el7ost.noarch

openstack-neutron-12.1.0-2-el7ost.noarch

openstack-neutron-blablabla-el7ost.noarch

openstack-neutron-blablabla1-el7ost.noarch

openstack-neutron-blablabla2-el7ost.noarch

openstack-neutron-blablabla3-el7ost.noarch

First two must pass, if I have a number after "neutron-" that's fine.

Comment: i need the **exact** json to find patterns

Comment: It's huge, I cannot send... I just can send this json example,  it's an array by the way

{openstack-neutron-1-el7ost.noarch, openstack-neutron-12.1.0-2-el7ost.noarch, openstack-neutron-blablabla-el7ost.noarch, openstack-neutron-blablabla1-el7ost.noarch, openstack-neutron-blablabla2-el7ost.noarch, openstack-neutron-blablabla3-el7ost.noarch}